# Google Map API v3 - Zoom parameter don't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using an Google API v3 but this parameter 'zoom : 10' is not working. Always I call the google api, the zoom is on max and I have to click on "-" about 5 times to get the desired zoom. I tried to put zoom: 1 and zoom: 100 but nothing happens. Maybe this parameter is being overwritten, but I can't see where.

Here is my code:

```
function viewOnMap(campus_name, lat, long, address1, address2){
  var locations = [ [ campus_name, lat, long, 1 ] ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_map'), {
    zoom : 10,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),  //lat long site
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat,
                        long),
                        map : map,
                        icon:'images/pin.png'
            });
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    bounds.extend(pos);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
                var content = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">Site name: '+ (campus_name) +
                '</div>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">Address: '+ (address1) +
                '</div>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent1">'+ (address2) +
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            }
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);    
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are your marker locations?  Are you calling map.fitBounds somewhere (not shown)? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see that problem [with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/rh2xh2o2/), I did have to fix some syntax errors identified by the jsfiddle "JSHint" function (jslint clone) to get it to display a map though,

Comment: map.fitBounds(bounds);
(: this code is there, I forgot to put here.
@geocodezip I'll try using your code, thanks.

Comment: Please update your code to be **complete**

Comment: sorry, the code is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to google.maps.Map.fitBounds overrides the fixed zoom in the MapOptions.

If you only add one position to a google.maps.LatLngBounds, then use google.maps.Map.fitBounds, it will always zoom to the maximum possible zoom.

If you only have one position, don't use google.maps.Map.fitBounds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried. :

```
map.setZoom(10);
```

I would even try setting it after you set your markers.

In fact if you want to see if it works debug your code in chrome set a breakpoint after map has been rendered and run that code in the local window.

Comment: What are you doing with the bounds variable which you are extending for each new marker position? Like @geocodezip said, are you passing this to a fitBounds call later on? There must be more code you can give us?